# Can JOptionPane be included in a branching program (if)?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, branch, joptionpane

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRD12.png)

This is my school assignment. I want to make a program using Scanner and JOptionPane. But my program is stuck on branching. Can anyone help me? Somehow the JOptionPane doesn't want to appear. I want that when I type the number 1, the OPtionPane will appear. I'm a complete newbie at this.

This is the script:

```
       int choice;
       
       do{
           System.out.print("MAIN MENU" + "\n--------------------"
                   + "\nOption Menu :" + "\n1. LOGIN" + "\n2. EXIT" + "\n--------------------" + "\nYour choice: ");
           choice = in.nextInt();
           
           if(choice == 1){
               String user = "";
               user = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Username : ");
               
               String pass = "";
               pass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Password : ");
       } while (choice != 2);
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Currently we don't know what `dataLogin` is and does. (Btw: Java Naming Conventions says that class names shall start uppercase) Please [edit] your question accordingly, and also add the input, output and expected output.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time asking on Stack Overflow

Comment: Don't worry, be sure to check out the link I posted and to edit your question accordingly. For further reference, be sure to take the [tour] and have a look at [ask]

Comment: Is my qustion appropriate?

Comment: No, you have not provided a [mre]. Somebody trying to help you cannot simply take your code and run it themselves. So try to fix all compilation problems and to provide the correct code, otherwise people won't be able to help you.

Comment: It does display JOptionPane on my system. Java 11, Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.